# Running a Generic Python Job on GCP

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, jobs, prediction

I have created and trained an ML model using sklearn and GCP AI Platform. I trained the model by submitting a job on AI Platform

https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/ai-platform/jobs/submit/training

I now want to get predictions from this model, but the accompanying documentation

https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/ai-platform/jobs/submit/prediction

doesn't seem to allow for any personal scripting. This is important because my input data needs to be pre-processed and transformed before being input to the model.  Is there any way that I can command multiple workers to do this on GCP and just submit my python script?

The basic thing I want to be able to do is take my large csv (about 5 mil rows), transform one column to the proper input format for the model and apply the model (I can do this via .apply, I believe), writing the output to a new column, and output the new dataframe to memory.

Comment: Do you know the memory footprint of your process? How many do you need to process this? Do you require GPU?

Comment: If DataFrame.apply() works row by row, then memory is not an issue. It has been running locally on my computer for 24 hours now, so I don't think that is the case. If DataFrame.apply() works on the entire column at once, then it will be a memory issue because at some point in the function being applied, the input is transformed into a (1,20000) sparse array, before being transformed back into an integer.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere I have benchmarked the process and it looks like it is doing about 30 records per second on my VM.

Comment: It run slowly!! 30 records per seconds, if you have 5 millions of row it take 2 days! Does it possible to split the CSV, for example in 1000 piece of 5000 rows and then to perform the process? What do you do with the result of the process, the new dataframe in memory?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere I could do that, but I’d prefer something more scalable. I am trying to learn how to do the process in beam, but am not quite sure what exactly my code needs to be.

Comment: Dataflow,  and beam, is also a solution, not the cheapest but a good choice anyway. With  Beam, you start with a FileIO to read your file, line by line. Then you have to parse your line (split the CSV and put your value in a structure, like a dict). And finally call your process on each line. At the end, store the result in what you want: a file, a database,...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217610/discussion-between-swygerts-and-guillaume-blaquiere).